How to Laravel app become socket listener
Internet has many samples of socket communication between Laravel application and Javascript frontend.
Unfortunately, all these samples belongs to just one scenario:

Laravel app initiate communication and push own data
Javascript front subscribes to this data by listening channel.

But what about reversive behaviour:

Javascript front push own data (many samples exists)
Laravel app subscribes on this data by listening channel (none samples).

How to implement Laravel part?
For sure, I can write listener for internal Laravel events. But what about listening socket with external data?

typically you would just make an http request to the server. if you want the server to "listen" for the client then you need a long running websockets server which Laravel does not do

if using Laravel reverb you can listen for the Laravel\Reverb\Events\MessageReceived event
You can see a demonstration from Laracon EU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrL5eCMpqtc

In Laravel, the server cannot "listen" to an event coming from the client in the same sense as the subscriber in a publish/subscribe architecture does.
However, I want to share a solution I've been working on for a while, and it addresses the (Laravel as a socket listener) part of this question.
Assuming that Socket.IO is being used and run on a separate server, the client will open a bidirectional channel with the server.

When the client sends a message, the Socket.IO server receives it and pass it to the Laravel application in one of multiple ways, but perhaps an HTTP could be the simplest one, and this means that the Socket.IO server performs an HTTP request to the Laravel application internally, which should be blazing fast if both Socket.IO server and the web server that hosts the Laravel application lives on the same server.

The Laravel application receives the incoming message from the Socket.IO server and enqueues it for later broadcasting.

The message is dequeued and sent to a broker (e.g. Redis).

The Socket.IO is watching the broker for any new messages to broadcast back to the other clients.


In this scenario, we assume that Laravel is using the Redis broadcast driver.
This is doable, and I've done it before, but it needs a lot of security revisions and optimizations, and I didn't take it to production, but I'm just listing it for the principal.


Note: There's a real-time messaging server called Centrifugo that works the same way, and it can be integrated with Laravel as well through the broadcast driver implemented by Denis Zakharenko
